# How to stop a phone call using cordova?

Tags: cordova

I am currently using cordova-plugin-phone-call, to initiate a phone call, which is working fine.

For a application I would like to stop any phone calls first, before making a new phone call. Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Update: I solved the problem myself, by modyfing cordova-plugin-phone-call. I added a endCall function in Java. I share the code here if somebody wants to know how.

Here is the code: (/java/com/cordova.phonedialer/PhoneDialer.java)

```
package org.apache.cordova.phonedialer;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.List;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.telecom.TelecomManager;

public class PhoneDialer extends CordovaPlugin {
    public static final int CALL_REQ_CODE = 0;
    public static final int ANSWER_PHONE_REQ_CODE = 0;
    public static final int PERMISSION_DENIED_ERROR = 20;
    public static final String CALL_PHONE = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
    public static final String ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS = Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS;

    private CallbackContext callbackContext;        // The callback context from which we were invoked.
    private JSONArray executeArgs;

    protected void getCallPermission(int requestCode) {
        cordova.requestPermission(this, requestCode, CALL_PHONE);
    }

    protected void getAnswerPhonePermission(int requestCode)
    {
        cordova.requestPermission(this, requestCode, ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
        this.executeArgs = args;

        System.out.println("Calling Action:"+action);

        try {
            if("call".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                if (cordova.hasPermission(CALL_PHONE)) {
                    callPhone(executeArgs);
                } else {
                    getCallPermission(CALL_REQ_CODE);
                }
            } else if ("dial".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                dialPhone(executeArgs);
            }
            else if("end".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){

                if( cordova.hasPermission(ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS) )
                {
                    endCall();
                }
                else
                {
                    getAnswerPhonePermission(ANSWER_PHONE_REQ_CODE);
                }
            }

            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = "Exception Dialing Phone Number: " + e.getMessage();
            System.err.println(msg);
            callbackContext.error(msg);

            return false;
        }

        // try {
        //  String phoneNumber = args.getString(0);
        //  Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber);
        //  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        //  callIntent.setData(uri);
        //  this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(callIntent);
        //  callbackContext.success();
        //  return true;
        // } catch (Exception e) {
        //  String msg = "Exception Dialing Phone Number: " + e.getMessage();
        //  System.err.println(msg);
        //  callbackContext.error(msg);
        //  return false;
        // }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                        int[] grantResults) throws JSONException {
    for (int r : grantResults) {
        if (r == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, PERMISSION_DENIED_ERROR));
            return;
        }
    }
        switch (requestCode) {
        case CALL_REQ_CODE:
            callPhone(executeArgs);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void callPhone(JSONArray args) throws JSONException {
        String number = args.getString(0);
        number = number.replaceAll("#", "%23");

        if (!number.startsWith("tel:")) {
            number = String.format("tel:%s", number);
        }

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(isTelephonyEnabled() ? Intent.ACTION_CALL : Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(number));

            boolean bypassAppChooser = Boolean.parseBoolean(args.getString(1));
            if (bypassAppChooser) {
                intent.setPackage(getDialerPackage(intent));
            }

            cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            this.callbackContext.success();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            this.callbackContext.error("CouldNotCallPhoneNumber");
        }
    }


    private void dialPhone(JSONArray args) throws JSONException {
        String number = args.getString(0);
        number = number.replaceAll("#", "%23");

        if (!number.startsWith("tel:")) {
            number = String.format("tel:%s", number);
        }

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(isTelephonyEnabled() ? Intent.ACTION_DIAL : Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(number));

            boolean bypassAppChooser = Boolean.parseBoolean(args.getString(1));
            if (bypassAppChooser) {
                intent.setPackage(getDialerPackage(intent));
            }

            cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            this.callbackContext.success();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            this.callbackContext.error("CouldNotCallPhoneNumber");
        }
    }

    private boolean isTelephonyEnabled() {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return tm != null && tm.getPhoneType() != TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE;
    }

    private String getDialerPackage(Intent intent) {
        PackageManager packageManager = (PackageManager) cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (int i = 0; i < activities.size(); i++) {
            if (activities.get(i).toString().toLowerCase().contains("com.android.server.telecom")) {
                return "com.android.server.telecom";
            }
            if (activities.get(i).toString().toLowerCase().contains("com.android.phone")) {
                return "com.android.phone";
            } else if (activities.get(i).toString().toLowerCase().contains("call")) {
                return activities.get(i).toString().split("[ ]")[1].split("[/]")[0];
            }
        }
        return "";
    }


    private boolean endCall()
    {
        TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
        boolean success = false;

        if (tm != null) {
            success = tm.endCall();
            // success == true if call was terminated.
            return success;
        }

        return success;
    }

}
```

and also dont forget to add the function in Javascript file /assets/plugins/cordova-plguin-phone-call.www/dialer.js

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-phone-call.phonedialer", function(require, exports, module) {
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
var platformId = require('cordova/platform').id;

module.exports = {

    /**
     * Call the native dialer
     *
     * @param {String, Function}      The phone number to call, The callback error function
     */
    dial: function(phnum, errorCallback, successCallback, bypassAppChooser) {
        if (phnum == null) errorCallback("empty");
        if (platformId == 'ios' || platformId == 'android') {
            exec(
                successCallback, 
                errorCallback, 
                "PhoneDialer", 
                "dial", 
                [phnum, bypassAppChooser]
            );
        } else {
            document.location.href = "tel:" + phnum;
            if (successCallback) successCallback();
        }
    },
    call: function(phnum, errorCallback, successCallback, bypassAppChooser) {
        if (phnum == null) errorCallback("empty");
        if (platformId == 'ios' || platformId == 'android') {
            exec(
                successCallback, 
                errorCallback, 
                "PhoneDialer", 
                "call", 
                [phnum, bypassAppChooser]
            );
        } else {
            document.location.href = "tel:" + phnum;
            if (successCallback) successCallback();
        }
    },
    end: function(phnum, errorCallback, successCallback, bypassAppChooser) {
        if (platformId == 'ios' || platformId == 'android') {

            exec(
                successCallback,
                errorCallback,
                "PhoneDialer",
                "end",
                [phnum, bypassAppChooser]
            );

            successCallback();

        } else
        {
            document.location.href = "tel:" + phnum;
            if (successCallback) successCallback();
        }
    }






};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as per [end call event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#endcallbutton)

```
document.addEventListener("endcallbutton", onEndCallKeyDown, false);

function onEndCallKeyDown() {
    // Handle the end call button
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this will be executed when the user press the end call button, but I need  the end call button to be triggered programmatically without user interactions.